# How to synthesize a thunder sound with bandpass filter

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing, sound-synthesis

I am working on synthesizing sound of thunder in MATLAB.
I had generated pink noise and now I'm trying to add bandpass filter on 30Hz, but I am getting the error:

```
The frequency specifications Fpass, Fstop must have increasing values.
```

Here's my code:

```
dur=[0:1/Fs:time-1/Fs];
sz=length(dur);
g=randn(1, sz); %
Y=fft(g);

NumUniquePts = sz/2 + 1;
n = 1:NumUniquePts;
n = sqrt(n);
Y(1:NumUniquePts) = Y(1:NumUniquePts)./n;

Y(NumUniquePts+1:sz) = real(Y(sz/2:-1:2)) -1i*imag(Y(sz/2:-1:2));

y = ifft(Y);

y = real(y(1, 1:sz));

y = y - mean(y);
yrms = sqrt(mean(y.^2));
y = y/yrms;

d = fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',30,10,0.5,50,48e4);
Hd1 = design(d,'equiripple');
Hd2 = design(d,'butter');

out = filter(Hd1,y);
```

Maybe there an other way to synthesize it?

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: error is "The frequency specifications Fpass, Fstop must have increasing values."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting an error. "The frequency specifications Fpass, Fstop must have increasing values."

This error means that `Fstop` should be greater than `Fpass`. You mentioned that you need `Fpass=30Hz`. So you would need `Fstop > 30`, but you specified a value of 10Hz. To fix this error you should increase the `Fstop` value (for example to 100Hz for starters then tweak until you get what you like).

Comment: Thank you for answer, i have changed value to 100Hz, but now script just don't work.

Comment: @VadimTor "just don't work" as in you get another error, or not produce the audio that sounds the way you want? For the later, that's why I mentioned "tweak until you get what you like".

Comment: I have used 480kHz sampling frequency and my computer just freezed, when i was trying to run it. So now its works perfect, thank you again.